# How can I switch between child objects using @autowired tag in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there any way to inject one of the child objects using @autowired tag?

```html
public class Provider {
 
    @Autowired
    private ParentFeedAPI feedAPI;

}


public abstract class ParentFeedAPI {

}

public class Child1FeedAPI extends ParentFeedAPI{

}

public class Child2FeedAPI extends ParentFeedAPI{

}
```

[Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HawJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adhere to  [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation, and name you're bean by using e.g. *@Component* (or a better fitting spring stereotype annotation), something like

```
public class Provider {

    @Qualifier("child1")
    @Autowired
    private ParentFeedAPI feedAPI;

}

public interface ParentFeedAPI {

}

@Component("child1")
public class Child1FeedAPI implements ParentFeedAPI{

}

@Component("child2")
public class Child2FeedAPI implements ParentFeedAPI{

}
```

Also, try to program against an interface

Comment: Thnaks  !! I got the this exception : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ParentFeedAPI] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: child1,child2

Comment: It most likely mean you've missed the annotation qualifier beside the autowire

Comment: Bingo :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Np :) glad it helped

Comment: Is there anyway to setup some sort of list object, and then give a manual ordering in the list. If it fails to autowire child1, try to autowire child2 ?!

Comment: No, but you can checkout spring profiles, which will allow wiring different objects in different context